# Html paragraph and fieldset in the same line

Tags: html, css

I want the `<div>`'s child fieldset and the paragraph to be on the same line.

**The Code:**

```css
fieldset {
  width: 180px;
}
#login p {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    Username  <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password  <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </fieldset>
  <p>Here you can login or signup for our website</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fieldset` is a block-element too! You have to set `display:inline` for `fieldset` too, like the following solution:

**Solution using only `display:inline` without `float`:**

```css
#login {
  background:blue;
}
fieldset {
  display:inline;
  width:180px;
}
#login p {
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    Username  <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password  <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </fieldset>
  <p>Here you can login or signup for our website</p>
</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
```

**Solution using `float` with `clear` (to avoid the chaos!):**

By using `float` you have to set the `clear` property!

```css
#login {
  background:blue;
}
#login:after {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
fieldset {
  float:left;
  width: 180px;
}
#login p {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    Username  <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password  <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </fieldset>
  <p>Here you can login or signup for our website</p>
</div>
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this css**

```
#login fieldset {
    width: 180px;
   float:left;
 }

    #login p {
    float:left;

 }
```